# How to check to see if a scrollbar is present in React?

Tags: reactjs, scroll

I haven't seen a thread that handles this, at least not for React.

My case: I want to conditionally render a back to top button only when scrolling is an option. It makes no sense to have such a feature if it can't affect the page.

The only solutions I can find are in jQuery. I'm using react-scroll but couldn't find any functionality there for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luke.

By "scrolling is an option" I am assuming here that you mean "when the scrollbar is visible."

As far as I am aware, there is not any way to check for scrollbar visibility using the React API. There is the DOM boolean `window.scrollbars.visible`; however, I have not had luck with this. It seems to always return `true` whether a scrollbar is visible or not. The following approach *may* work for you:

You could set an event listener for onScroll and check window.scrollY. If `window.scrollY > 0`, then you could conditionally render the button. If `window.scrollY` is `0`, then the page is already scrolled to the top and there is no need to display the button.

Depending on the design of your web app, checking once for scrollbar visibility (e.g., on `componentDidMount`) may not be the best option, since some DOM elements may continue to load after the component initially mounts and the height of the page may change.

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 5):

To check if scrollbar is visible in vertical appearance.

```
document.body.clientHeight > window.innerHeight
```

I added this code in a useEffect.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (document.body.clientHeight > window.innerHeight) {
      something()
    }
  }, [state]);
```

Answer (score 3):

When a scrollbar is visible then window.visualViewport.width < window.Width.

```
var buttonIsVisible = window.visualViewport.width < window.Width;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a wrapper around the element that has the scroll you can detect the width difference.

```
<div className="wrapper">
  <div className="scrollingContent">
    Very long content here
  </div>
</div>

const scrollBarWidth = this.wrapper.clientWidth - this.scrollingContent.clientWidth;
this.setState({ scrollBarWidth });
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time (depending on edge cases where elements are sized differently). You can use an element ref to check if the scrollWidth is greater than the current width (or height for vertical scroll). The ref might not update scroll properties with useEffect hence why you need state in the dependencies array. Plus you will likely want to add a window resize event listener to run the same code.

```
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const [hasScrollBar, setHasScrollBar] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
      function updateState() {
         const el = ref.current;
         el && setHasScrollBar(el.scrollWidth > el.getBoundingClientRect().width);
      }

      updateState();

      window.addEventListener('resize', updateState);
      return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', updateState);
   }, [state]);

  <div ref={ref} style={{ overflowX: 'auto' }}>
    {state}
  </div>
```